# app not deploying to heroku

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, deployment

I am having a problem with deploying my app on heroku.  I am stuck and cannot find the answer. I have went through the heroku troubleshooting and deployment procedures. I have been trying for 3 days. I have rewritten my env file numerous times and every time I do, it doesn't work on localhost. I have MONGOD and NODEMON running. I reverted back to the original and it is working.  But still will not deploy on heroku. Thanks in advance.

Here is what my env.js looks like

```
module.exports = {
  db: process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/sailcast',
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000
}
```

package.json

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "gulp default"
  },
    "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.4.0",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-sessions": "^1.0.6",
    "express-static": "^1.2.5",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.5",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "yarn": "^1.7.0",
    "yarn.lock": "0.0.1-security"
  },

    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.4",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

Here are the heroku logs. I can't figure out the error. just keep getting application error

```
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.831441+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sailcast@1.0.0       
    start: `node index.js`
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.831595+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.831982+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
    sailcast@1.0.0 start script.
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.831821+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.832134+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably 
    not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.839530+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.839805+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of 
    this run can be found in:
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.839898+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
    /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-16T02_00_26_833Z-debug.log
    2018-06-16T02:00:26.898270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
    status 1
    2018-06-16T02:00:27.233835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
    starting to crashed
    2018-06-16T05:23:18.892587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
    crashed to starting
    2018-06-16T05:23:22.696724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
    command `npm start`
    2018-06-16T05:23:24.791728+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T05:23:24.791759+00:00 app[web.1]: > sailcast@1.0.0 start /app
    2018-06-16T05:23:24.791761+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
    2018-06-16T05:23:24.791762+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449215+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:681
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449238+00:00 app[web.1]: return 
    process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449240+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449242+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449244+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: 
    /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449247+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449245+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449249+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449250+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449252+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449253+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449257+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
    (module.js:652:30)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449258+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449260+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449261+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449263+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449264+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449266+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449267+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/app/models/user.js:2:16)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
    (module.js:652:30)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449270+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449271+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449273+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449274+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449276+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.449277+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.457003+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.457360+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.458445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sailcast@1.0.0 
    start: `node index.js`
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.458586+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.458827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.458989+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
    sailcast@1.0.0 start script.
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.459138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably 
    not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.493154+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.493346+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of 
    this run can be found in:
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.493475+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
   /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-16T05_23_25_460Z-debug.log
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.564550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
    status 1
    2018-06-16T05:23:25.653739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
    starting to crashed
    2018-06-16T10:54:29.552763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
    crashed to starting
    2018-06-16T10:54:35.778827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
    command `npm start`
    2018-06-16T10:54:39.194359+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T10:54:39.194379+00:00 app[web.1]: > sailcast@1.0.0 start /app
    2018-06-16T10:54:39.194381+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
    2018-06-16T10:54:39.194383+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337060+00:00 app[web.1]: return 
    process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337027+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:681
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337063+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337065+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337067+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: 
    /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337069+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337071+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337073+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337074+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337077+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337076+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337079+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337080+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
    (module.js:652:30)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337082+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337084+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337087+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337085+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337088+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337090+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337091+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/app/models/user.js:2:16)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337093+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
    (module.js:652:30)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337094+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337096+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load 
    (module.js:565:32)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337097+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad 
    (module.js:505:12)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337099+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (module.js:497:3)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337100+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (module.js:596:17)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.337102+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
    (internal/module.js:11:18)
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.348452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code 
    ELIFECYCLE
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.350021+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.355451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! sailcast@1.0.0 
    start: `node index.js`
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.356150+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.357519+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.358261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
    sailcast@1.0.0 start script.
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.359222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably 
    not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.384205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.384792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of 
    this run can be found in:
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.385145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
    /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-16T10_54_40_366Z-debug.log
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.480586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
    starting to crashed
    2018-06-16T10:54:40.461008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
    status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine. One thing that came up to my mind is that if your file called app.js or index.js since it is an error with npm start? Maybe you made a typo.

Another thing that came up to my mind is that, if you set up the environment database value from the heroku. Since, I cannot see your whole heroku logs, it is another possibility

Comment: Ugur, thanks.  I figured it out about 2 hours ago.  Everything was running correct, except that i had forgoteen to put my .gitignore file in.  As soon as i popped that in it deployed and is now running.  Thank you.